# Can I block social share buttons with Privoxy?

Tags: adblock, privoxy

A great many pages have these "Like", "Tweet", "G+1", "share" row of buttons all over the place and in each post in threads. Can I block these unwanted context **with Privoxy**?

I am already using Privoxy and it blocks a lot of unwanted content, but still these "social" buttons are all over the place.

I want to completely remove these buttons specifically by using Privoxy. I know that it is possible to block using AdBlock LITE and other software, but my question is specific to Privoxy (reason, I want one point to block all unwanted content and it needs to work on devices / softwares which do not have AdBlock LITE, therefore I use Privoxy).

--

Software used: Privoxy 3.0.21 under Windows XP

Comment: I doubt that share buttons hosted locally on a site can be blocked, even uBlock Origin can't block, only hide.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read into the [Action Files](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html) for Privoxy. Here are a few examples of custom actions in Privoxy.

**Block Facebook:**

```
{+block{Block Facebook.}}
.facebook.
.fbcdn.
```

**Block Various Tracker Domains:**

```
{+block{Block Yahoo Analytics}}
s.yimg.com
.analytics.yahoo.com

{+block{Block Google Analytics and ads}}
.google-analytics.
.googleadservices.com
plusone.google.com
.googlesyndication.com

{+block{Block Twitter buttons}}
platform.twitter.com/widgets
```

**Block Image Trackers:**

```
{+block{Block web bugs} +handle-as-image}
.2mdn./.*\.[gif|jpg|png]
feeds.feedburner.com
.feedburner.com/.*[gif|jpg|png]$
s.ytimg.com/.*pixel.*gif$
```

As a side note; I personally like to use [ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/) for similar solutions with a nifty command like this;

```
ngrep -q 'facebook.com' -K 10
```

Which simply kills any tcp connection that matches that regular expression.

Comment: Your answer only blocks domains it seems, many share buttons are hosted locally and can be hidden with this filter (hide Facebook hyperlinks) in uBlock Origin: `##[href*="facebook.com"]`